# Android resources for languages with only 3 letter codes

Tags: android, locale

While trying to add localized resources for the [Sakha language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sakha_language) in my android app, I kept getting errored out with the following message:

```
[aapt] invalid resource directory name: /Users/yuvipanda/code/WikipediaMobile/res/values-bho

BUILD FAILED
/Users/yuvipanda/adk/tools/ant/build.xml:539: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/yuvipanda/adk/tools/ant/build.xml:568: null returned: 1
```

Trying to add variants for *any* three letter language code gives me the same error (`values-bho`, `values-kbd`, `values-sah`, etc).

Is there a trick I'm missing, or does Android not support having localizations for languages with only 3 letter language codes?

Answer (score 1):

From [Providing Alternative Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) in the developer guides, it looks like Android supports only two-letter [ISO 639-1](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) language codes.

Comment: That was my reading too. I'm looking to confirm before I file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The naming convention is different for apps that include three letter language codes.  Instead of having your resources in the folder `values-bho`, put them into a folder called `values-b+bho`.  the `-b+` identifies the following language tags as pertaining to [BCP 47](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag) (language codes, dialects, regions, scripts, and the rest of the kitchen sink), rather than ISO 639-1 (two-letter codes).